# Linux архивирование по маске, где ошибка?

Tags: linux, tar, find

планирую архивировать файлы по маске
`find /mnt/smb-share/ -type f \( -name "*.rtf" -o -name "*.txt" \)  -exec tar -cv /var/ftp/arc-doc/doc-arc-$(date +%y%m%d).tar {}  \;`

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/mnt/smb-share/Отчет.rtf
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/mnt/smb-share/акт.rtf
```

архивирует последний наведенный файл
имя внутри архива почему то в виде *акт.rtf

Comment: Ключ `-f` для tar-a забыли ... `..... -exec tar -cvf /var/...`

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/513304/454489

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в том, что `find` запускает команду указанную в `-exec ... {} ;` отдельно для каждого найденного файла т.е. фактически происходит запуск следующих команд:

```
tar -cvf /var/ftp/arc-doc/doc-arc-20190711.tar /mnt/smb-share/Отчет.rtf
tar -cvf /var/ftp/arc-doc/doc-arc-20190711.tar /mnt/smb-share/акт.rtf
```

При этом каждая следующая перезаписывает архив полностью.

---

Есть несколько способов решить оную:

- использовать форму `-exec ... {} +`:

  ```
  find ... -exec tar cvf /var/ftp/arc-doc/doc-arc-$(date +%y%m%d).tar '{}' +
  ```

  Это приведёт к запуску одной команды со всеми файлами в качестве аргументов. Но если файлов будет слишком много (порядка нескольких десятков тысяч для современных linux-систем), они могут не поместиться в командной строке. И получится эффект аналогичный предыдущему: архив затрётся новым только с частью файлов
- использовать `xargs`:

  ```
  find ... | xargs -d '\n' tar cvf /var/ftp/arc-doc/doc-arc-$(date +%y%m%d).tar
  ```

  Возникает аналогичная проблема с большим количеством файлов + проблемы с файлами с абнормальными именами, в частности, с переводами строк в имени.
- Использовать режим дополнения tar-архива (ключик `r`):

  ```
  find ... -exec tar rvf /var/ftp/arc-doc/doc-arc-$(date +%y%m%d).tar '{}' \;
  ```

  Это решает проблему с количеством аргументов, но приводит к дополнительным расходам на запуск отдельного `tar`'а для каждого файла + если архив уже существует, то он не перезаписывается.
- Комбинация первого (или второго — по вкусу) и третьего:

  ```
  find ... -exec tar rvf /var/ftp/arc-doc/doc-arc-$(date +%y%m%d).tar '{}' +
  ```
- Использовать ключик `-T` (--files-from) `tar`'а, который заставляет читать список файлов для архивации из файла (`-`, как обычно означает стандартный ввод), в купе с конвейером:

  ```
  find ... | tar cvf /var/ftp/arc-doc/doc-arc-$(date +%y%m%d).tar -T -
  ```

  Проблема аналогичная способы с `xargs` с файлами с переводами строк в именах, а также с файлами с имеами начинающимися с минуса (`-`), первое обходится передачей `-print0`/`--null` `find`'у/`tar`'у соответственно, а второе — передачей `--verbatim-files-from` `tar`'у (нужна достаточно новая версия).

  <sub>Спасибо @aleksandrbarakin за замечание; Также см. [это](https://superuser.com/questions/513304/how-to-combine-the-tar-command-with-find/513319#513319).</sub>

---

**Замечания**

- Я так понимаю, что пропущенный ключик `f` в `tar`'е — это только опечатка в вопросе, но это всё же достойно упоминания.
- В данном виде в архиве будут файлы с абсолютными путями относительно корня `/mnt/smb-share/`; Обычно это не желательное поведение, о чём и предупреждает `tar`. Решить это можно предварительным переходом в нужный каталог:

  ```
  ( cd /mnt/smb-share/ &&  find . -type f ... -exec tar rvf ... '{}' +` )
  ```

---

**См. также:**
[man tar](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=tar&category=1); [man find](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=find&category=1&russian=2);

Comment: 1) а звездочка в именах откуда берется?

Comment: @pinkzebra, какие звёздочки?

Comment: в архиве получается файл вида *name.??? в данном случае *акт.rtf, при замене tar на cp все скопированные имена обзаводятся *name.???

Comment: @pinkzebra, что-то мне не верится... в архиве должны быть файлы с полным путём `mnt/smb-share/акт.rtf`, как в замечаниях отметил... чем просматривашь архив? возможно просто просмоторщик вместо пути каталога решил вывести звёздочку... для уверенности посмотри `tar tf /путь/к/архиву.tar`.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо, дополнил...

Comment: да вы были правы, это так отображал midnit midnight commander

Comment: 'find . -type f \( -name "*.rtf" -o -name "*.txt" \) -exec tar -cvf /var/arc-doc/$(date +%y%m%d).tar '{}' +'  **в таков виде работает** 'find . -type f \( -name "*.rtf" -o -name "*.txt" \) -exec tar -cvfz /var/ftp/ftpuser/iac86-doc/$(date +%y%m%d).tar.gz '{}' +' **tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors**

Comment: но тогда с такой работой find выгоднее упаковывать каждый файл в отдельный архив?

Comment: @pinkzebra, из очевидного вижу ошибку: `cvzf`, а не `cvfz` — после `f` сразу должно идти имя архива т.е. он создаёт архив с именем `z` и судя по всему не находит один из файлов (собственно тот, что с настоящим именем архива), чтобы запаковать туда, поэтому и жалуется...  по второму вопросу не понял, о чём речь...

Comment: Fat-Zer@ ***чуствую себя школьником (про то что F обязательно в конце непрозрачно)*** ***2)*** возможно что то типа такой подстановки ```find . -type f \( -name "*.rtf" -o -name "*.txt" \) -exec tar -cvzf /var/ftp/ftpuser/iac86-doc/*$'{}'*$(date +%y%m%d).tar.gz '{}' ``` что бы сохранилась структура каталога а каждый файл в отельном архиве? *** сколько параметров можно задать find . -type f \( -name "*.rtf" -o -name "*.txt" ***вот здесь*** \)

Comment: @pinkzebra, да так можно, по крайней мере GNU-find умеет подставлять `{}` несколько раз, но `tar` не умеет создавать поддиректории сам, так что его нужно будет совместить со скриптиком например как-то так: ` -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p "$(dirname bak/"$0")"' '{}' \; -exec tar -cvzf 'bak/{}.tar.gz' '{}' \;` … а через `-o` можно писать далее сколько угодно тестов, но практичнее будет перейти на регэкспы: `-regex '.*\.\(txt\|rtf\)'`… или `-iregex` для регистронезависимого поиска... ЗЫ: от оригинальной темы мы уже довольно сильно отошли — такое не возбраняется задавать в отдельных вопросах…